# Give the spherical coordinates representation of the following solids

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Give the **spherical coordinates** representation of the following solids:

(i) Inside the sphere $ \ x^2+y^2+z^2=4 \ $ and outside the cylinder $ \ x^2+y^2=1 \ $

(ii) Inside the sphere $ \ x^2+y^2+z^2=4 \ $ and above the plane $ \ z=3 \ $

**Answer;**

(i)

$ 0 \leq \rho \leq 2 \\ 0 \leq \phi \leq \frac{\pi}{4} \\ 0 \leq \theta  \leq 2 \pi \ $

**Am I right?**

Help me out

Answer (score 0):

Write the equations for the coordinates

\begin{eqnarray}
x &=& \rho \sin \theta \cos\phi \\
y &=& \rho \sin \theta \sin\phi \\
z &=& \rho \cos \theta
\end{eqnarray}

So that the cylindrical surface can be written as

\begin{eqnarray}
x^2+y^2 &=& \rho^2\sin^2\theta\cos^2\phi + \rho^2\sin^2\theta\sin^2\phi \\ 
&=& \rho^2\sin^2\theta(\cos^2\phi + \sin^2\phi) \\
&=&\rho^2\sin^2\theta \geq 1
\end{eqnarray}

Or equivalentely

$$
\rho |\sin\theta| > 1
$$